# Can I terminate the foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Is there any difference between the given code segments (with and without `;`):

```
                                             |
                                            \|/
foreach($errors->get_error_codes() as $error);
        if( strpos(ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$error)),'nvalid Username'))
```

and

```
foreach($errors->get_error_codes() as $error)
        if( strpos(ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$error)),'nvalid Username'))
```

Actually both of them give the same output. So can I terminate the for each loop before the statements.

Answer (score 2):

While using

```
foreach($errors->get_error_codes() as $error);
```

it will store last occured value in `$errors->get_error_codes()` as `$error` and then it checks for the condition and if you use

```
foreach($errors->get_error_codes() as $error)
            if( strpos(ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$error)),'nvalid Username'))
```

then each of `$errors->get_error_codes()` value will taken as `$error` and it checks for the condition.

Simply

```
foreach($errors->get_error_codes() as $error);
```

will loop but `$error` get the last element in that array

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **Break ;** to break the loop and **continue ;** if you want to break the current iteration only

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the same output because the $errors array contains only one entry.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach($errors->get_error_codes() as $error);`

this line will store the last element in `$error` variable and there is no {} block;

Not everyone knows about this behavior and it can cause unexpected results.

The other line affect only next line because there is no code block determined by {}.

You can break  the loop using **break;** keyword. You can also skip the iteration of loop using **continue** keyword.